# I am migrating a project from maven to bazel and getting error

Tags: bazel

i am following the official bazel documentation for migrating from maven to bazel and used rules_jvm_external to defined external dependencies in workspace file and Build file. But I am getting the follwing error.

```
C:/users/kunal_visoulia/_bazel_kunal_visoulia/3f5dzdsz/external/maven/BUILD:1212:1: in deps attribute of jvm_import rule @maven//:commons_digester_commons_digester: rule '@maven//:xml_apis_xml_apis' does not exist
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:everything' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '@maven//:commons_digester_commons_digester' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 724.364s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (4 packages loaded, 371 targets configured)
    Fetching @remotejdk11_win; Restarting.
```

i am using private nexus repo and also the official maven repo. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully reproduced your error and found the following workaround:

1. Add `xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01` and `junit:junit-dep:4.9` to your
   list of artifacts.
2. Add the `version_conflict_policy = "pinned"`
   attribute to maven_install.

The root cause is https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/issues/250. The missing dependencies are artifacts that relocated to new GAV coordinates, which the coursier resolver cannot handle yet. The general workaround is to manually add the legacy GAV coordinates into `maven_install`.

Specifically, xml-apis:xml-apis:2.0.2 relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2 (but 1.4.0.1 wasn't relocated), and junit:junit-dep:4.9 relocated to junit:junit.

Comment: @KunalVisoulia great! please accept the answer if your problem was solved.

Comment: Just accepted the answer. sorry i was intern at that time and then the pandemic happened.  Thanks again for the help.